# No such column with foreign key

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to connect to tables in my database with different ID's (`CustomerID`, `OrderID`). I use the following code to create my foreign key:

```
FOREIGN KEY("+ COLUMN_ORDER_ID + ") REFERENCES+TABLE_NAME_CUSTOMER + "(" + COLUMN_CUSTOMER_ID + "));";
```

I'm not posting the complete source code, because my first table works fine and I think the problem is the foreign key.

I filter my data with this method:

```
public List<Orders> getOrdersByCustomerID() {
    List<Orders> orderList = new ArrayList<Orders>();
    String query = "select " + COLUMN_ORDER_ID
            + "," + COLUMN_ORDER_NAME
            + "," + COLUMN_SETS
            + "," + COLUMN_REPEATS
            + "," + COLUMN_SECTION
            + " from " + TABLE_NAME_ORDERS
            + " where " + COLUMN_CUSTOMER_ID
            + "=" + COLUMN_ORDER_ID;
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Orders orders = new Orders(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getInt(2), cursor.getInt(3), cursor.getString(4));
            orderList.add(orders);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return orderList;
}
```

I get this error message:

> 06-26 17:11:26.154 10163-10163/com.xxx.xxx.xxx
>
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main process: com.xxx.xxx.xxx, PID: 10163
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column:
>   customerId(Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: select
>   orderId,orderName,sets,repeats,section from orders where
>   customerId=orderId,(OS error - 2:No such file or directory)

I think the connection between this two ids is incorrect, or must I commit the id from my customer table? Any tips? As per my understanding, a `Customer` can have multiple `Order`s. That's why I use the foreign key; I hope this is correct.

Comment: The error refers to a column (`customerId`)  which it did not find in the table (`orders`) - can you show us the structure (column names) of your `orders` table?

Comment: the customerId is a column in my costumer table, in my order table i don't have a column named costumerId

Comment: Then your query (as reflected in the error) is incorrect: `"select orderId,orderName,sets,repeats,section from orders where customerId=orderId..."` - why are you checking if the `customerId` (on table orders), is equal to an `orderId`? This should instead be customer ID which is passed as an argument to your function.

Comment: Please show full table definition of both tables, including the full foreign key definition. That will help answer questions like "Does `orders` table have a `customerId` column?" without us having to ask such questions one-at-a-time until we get the full picture of your problem. Of course, we already know the answer indirectly from the error message...

Comment: Given that error message says that `orders` table *doesn't* have a `customerId` column, how are the two tables associated? How do you know which order is for which customer?

Comment: In my customer table there are only the customer id and the customer name , my opinion was when i reference the table with a foreign key i can filter my customer id to his orders.. so i must commit a parameter customerId in my method anf also adf a column customerid in my orders?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I was wrong apparently queries are case-insensitive by default in mysql.

Edit:
In order to create a foreign key both tables must contain the ConsumerId. This allows you the establish a relationship using the foreign key.
Your query has to be changed as wel, after creating the foreign key. It should be something like this

```
select " + COLUMN_ORDER_IDq
        + "," + COLUMN_ORDER_NAME
        + "," + COLUMN_SETS
        + "," + COLUMN_REPEATS
        + "," + COLUMN_SECTION
        + " from " + TABLE_NAME_ORDERS + "," + TABLE_NAME_CUSTOMERS
        + " where " + TABLE_NAME_ORDERS +"." + COLUMN_CUSTOMER_ID
        + "=" + TABLE_NAME_CUSTOMERS + "." + COLUMN_CUSTOMER_ID
```

Comment: i have two tables and in my customer table i have a column costumerId , this is my references key to the second table oders with the orderId

Comment: Names in a SQL statement are not case-sensitive unless quoted.

Comment: Error message specifically says that there is no `customerId` column in the `orders` table.

Comment: @Andreas I am aware of that. He is trying to establish a relationship between the orders and customers table. So it is best for him to add the customerId to the orders table as well, so he is able to establish a one-to-many relationship between the customers an orders table.

Comment: Yes rockney , i want a relationship between my two tables , also i must have a colum costumerId in my customer and in my order table ?

Comment: yes. the database needs to know which order belongs to which user. You do this by having a customerId in your customer table, and a customerId in your orders table. By creating a foreign key, you cross-reference related data across tables.